# How can I measure the weight in Farseer?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, farseer-physics-engine

I have two different objects(star and rectangle) and I want to measure the entire weight that lies on the balance. How can I do that? Is it possible to know the entire weight that presses on the balance?

The rectangle is lying on the star, it is not possible to lie the rectangle on the balance.
You can see the balance in this picture:

[image]

Comment: Do u know their masses and gravity accel? mg?

Comment: Yes, but how can the balance know the mass of the blue rectangle if the blue rectangle doesn't touch the balance?